Mounting Canon focus by wire lens (EF 50mm f1.8 STM) to EOS 300
I recently got a Canon EOS 300 (the film version, not digital) and would like to buy a faster lens in addition to the kit lens which I received with it.
I see that the 50mm f1.8 STM is still in production, and together with it's price, it strikes to me as a non-brainer (even if it's not perfect, that's fine. If I want perfect quality, I shoot digital :D)
I'm mostly wondering about the focus by wire technology, though. Would there be any problems with the EOS 300 in this regard? I noticed that the autofocus especially in low-light of the EOS 300 is not perfect, so I think some fallback to manual focus is sometimes needed.
I am  mostly thinking of getting this version because it's available new already for 115€. The used versions of the previous model (I heard that they didn't change the optics) sell at about 80€, so I don't necessarily want to go through the trouble of buying used. In addition, I could just use it for my M200 with the adapter, and then it seems to me as similar to the EF-M 22mm in technology which I already own.

Although they both have the same number of elements/groups, the optics of the EF 50mm f/1.8 II (1990) and the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM (2015) are NOT exactly the same. The STM has closer minimum focus distance (MFD) and thus larger maximum magnification (MM). It also has a 7 blade instead of 5 blade aperture diaphragm which, though technically not part of the optics, can significantly affect the way an image taken with each lens will look.

It looks like Ken Rockwell tried it with everything up to an EOS 620. it looks like it has some quirks with certain focus settings, but if you flip the switch on the lens it should mostly just work.

I ended up buying that lense, and it works flawlessly on the EOS 300 :)
